# Transform a list of delayed rules with conditions to a new list of delayed rules

Tags: replacement, pattern-matching, algebraic-manipulation, algebra

I have a list of rules that implement some abstract algebras, for instance, that of the Pauli matrices,

```
rules = {
σ[z] ** σ[pm_/;MemberQ[{-1,1}, pm]] :> pm σ[pm],

σ[1] ** σ[-1] -> (1/2) (Id + σ[z]), ...
}
```

I want to transform automatically such rules about such an abstract algebra to a new set of rules for multiple identical copies (labeled by `n`) of the algebra, for example,

```
newRules = {
σ[z][n_] ** σ[pm_/;MemberQ[{-1,1}, pm]][n_] :> pm σ[pm][n],

σ[1][n_] ** σ[-1][n_] :> (1/2) (Id + σ[z][n]), ...
}
```

I wonder how to achieve such automation? Assume that I have a list of names `generators = {σ[z], σ[-1], σ[+1]}` stored to guide the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
rules = {σ[z] ** σ[pm_/;MemberQ[{-1,1}, pm]] :> pm σ[pm]
       , σ[1] ** σ[-1] -> (1/2) (Id + σ[z])}

Cases[rules, r : (a_ -> b_) | (a_ :> b_) :> 
  RuleDelayed @@ {
      a /. \[Sigma][x__] :> \[Sigma][x][n_]
    , b /. \[Sigma][x__] :> \[Sigma][x][n]
}]
```

[image]